# Onclick strictly JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove JS from my HTML and I am having a hard time. I removed the onclick and implemented it into my JavaScript. It doesn't function as if it was still in my HTML.

```html
  <div class="shirt1" onclick="showItemDetails('shirt1')">
            <img src="shirt1.jpg" alt="shirt1">
            <h2>90s Salem Sportswear Miami Hurricanes Lightning (AOP) Tee Size XL</h2>
            <h4>Condition: Like New</h4>
           <h3>$300</h3> 
           <h5> offer</h5>
        </div>
```

For my JavaScript I have the following code:

```
function showItemDetails(shirtId) {
    const shirt = document.getElementById(shirtId);
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const shirts = document.querySelectorAll('.shirt');
    shirts.forEach(function(shirt) {
        shirt.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const shirtId = shirt.id;
            showItemDetails(shirtId);
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried the following code above, I also have tried implementing other ways but still cannot figure this out.

Comment: `querySelectorAll('.shirt')` means that there should be an element with the class of `shirt` in your HTML, which there isn't.

Comment: `showItemDetails` is also using `getElementById(shirtId)` but no div has an id. I believe what you wanna do, is change your div to `<div class="shirt" id="shirt1>`

Comment: You don't really need the ids - you could just pass the shirt element into showItemDetails

Comment: Hey @Steffen I have tried implementing a details div into the HTML but it still would not load properly.

Comment: @James ok, taking an attempt at doing it that way currently.

Comment: Thanks to all, I was able to fix this thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any elements with class `shirt`, so your `querySelectorAll()` will always return an empty list. Here's an updated version that fixes that.

```js
function showItemDetails(shirt) {
    shirt.classList.toggle('open');
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const shirts = document.querySelectorAll('.shirt');
    shirts.forEach(function(shirt) {
        shirt.addEventListener('click', () => showItemDetails(shirt));
    });
});
```

```css
.shirt > .details {
  display: none;
}
.shirt.open > .details {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="shirt">
    <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1017986/2626/i/450/depositphotos_26263587-stock-photo-man-in-blank-t-shirt.jpg" alt="shirt1">
    <div class="details">
      <h2>90s Salem Sportswear Miami Hurricanes Lightning (AOP) Tee Size XL</h2>
      <h4>Condition: Like New</h4>
     <h3>$300</h3> 
     <h5> offer</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```